# Record live elapsed time of PHP script

Tags: php, email, loops, cron

Say my `set_time_limit` is set to 30 seconds and can't be changed. I have an email script in php that will run longer than 30 seconds on 1 cron job (I haven't reached that time mark yet.) What happens on timeout after 30 seconds? Will the script stop then continue?

If not, I would like to record the elapsed time from the beginning of my script's loop until it reaches 30 seconds and pause the process then continue.

What is a good way to do this?

**Update: what I think might work**

```
function email()
{
  sleep(2); //delays script 2 seconds (time to break script on reset)

  foreach ($emails as $email): 
       // send individual emails with different content
       // takes longer than 30 seconds
   enforeach;

   // on 28 seconds
   return email(); //restarts process
}
```

Comment: What are some things you have tried?

Comment: After 30 seconds, a fatal error will be emitted and the script will be terminated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @sixeightzero nothing that I'm confident in.. for this reason I'm asking for guidance.

Comment: What have you searched for? Surely there are tutorials on how to accomplish batch tasks with PHP under a time limit.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder updated post with what I think might work

Comment: @CyberJunkie Timeouts are for an entire script, not a function. Calling the function again will not evade the limit. Try running the same script multiple times with cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested approach:

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();
foreach ($emails as $email): 
   // send individual emails with different content
   // takes longer than 30 seconds

   $time_curr = microtime_float();
   $time = $time_curr - $time_start;
   if($time > 28){ //if time is bigger than 28 seconds (2 seconds less - just in case)
        break;// we will continue processing the rest of the emails - next time cron will call the script
   }
enforeach;
```

Comment: If you have PHP >= 5.0 you can just use `microtime(true)` to retrieve as float.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not possible. When the script timeout is reached, it stops. You cannot pause it and continue it. You can only restart it. Let me tell you what I did to solve a similar problem.

```
Part One:
Queue all your emails into a simple database. (Just a few fields like to,
 from, subject, message, and a flag to track if it is sent.)

Part Two.
1. Start script
2. Set a variable with the start time
3. Check the db for any mails that have not been sent yet
4. If you find any start a FOR loop
5. Check if more than 20 seconds have elapsed (adjust the window here, I like 
   to allow some spare time in case a mail call takes a few seconds longer.)
6. If too much time passed, exit the loop, go to step 10
7. Send an email
8. Mark this email as sent in the db
9. The FOR loop takes us back to step 4
10. Exit the script
```

Run this every 60 seconds. It sends what it can, then the rest gets sent next time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I was thinking about a similar approach but without checking time elapsed. I don't see a point if I'm running the script every minute

Comment: The point is because of your initial question. Consider if you do not check time elapsed, and an email is sent, but the script is aborted before the email is marked at sent. That person will get a duplicate email. Consider also that your host may change the timeout value, or you use the script on another host. Checking time elapsed leaves you in control and lets you stop the script ahead of time, rather than relying on the timeout to end it for you.